# Como obtener dos variables que cuenten expresiones en SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podría ayudareme en esto, tengo problemas en Como obtener en una sola consulta dos variables que cuenten expresiones en SQL, en este caso de la imagen sería la cantidad de proyectos con estado 2 y cantidad de proyectos con estado 3. Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo no utilices imagenes para explicar algo mejor pon como tienes tu codigo y si puedes explicar mejor que es lo que quieres lograr y como tienes tu bd

Comment: gracias ya vi la solución, un placer el que hayas querido ayudarme...

Comment: resolvi con esto  SELECT  proyecto.id_entidad,
   
    SUM(CASE WHEN proyecto.id_estado= '2'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroActivo', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN proyecto.id_estado= '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS 'RegistroNoActivo'
    FROM proyecto
    GROUP BY proyecto.id_entidad